# Can any deadbolt be made to work without an outer lock?

Tags: lock

I am planning a secondary entrance door that does not need to be openable from the outside. So, if I have a deadbolt on the door, I just need a twist lever on the inside and no lock on the outside.

When I look at deadbolts in catalogs, however, they all seem to have key holes and plates on the outside. Is it possible to just leave this part of the lock out, or do I need to find a deadbolt that is specifically designed to have just a lever on one side and no lock? If so, what is that called?

Comment: Just cause there is a key hole on one side does not mean you have to use it, plus there are many other options to lock a door from inside.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is easily and cheaply available.  The relevant keywords are "one sided deadbolt" or "keyless deadbolt".

Home Depot, for example, [has a selection of them](https://www.homedepot.com/b/One-sided-Keyless-Deadbolt/N-5yc1vZ1z118vn) that start at $7.

If you already have a deadbolt you want to use, some companies sell a conversion kit to replace the keyway with a blank plate.  [Here's one from Kwikset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0156KB96C).  However, that's more expensive than just buying a new one sided deadbolt, so I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: Because the blank plate fits a *far higher-quality* deadbolt than the "theater to prove we're trying to keep local kids out of our pool" tier locksets that you get for $7.  I mean the blanking plate probably weighs more than the whole $7 lockset lol...

Comment: @Harper, that makes sense in theory, but the conversion plate I linked was specific to a Kwikset 663 for $13, and home depot has a Kwikset 663 one-sided for $8.  So in this case it's the exact same deadbolt.  Home depot also has the higher-quality Kwikset 667 one-sided for $14.

Comment: DOh, well then it may be upward compatible with better locksets.  Although Kwikset only goes so high... I'm used to paying $120 for a deadbolt set, and that's not even Class I hardware...

Comment: It's upward-compatible with the 664, but the 667 uses a different one (that also costs $13).  I think it's just because it's an uncommon specialty item.  Looking around a little more, every conversion kit I've seen only saves about $2 or less (assuming you are counting the original lock as free) over just buying the one-sided version of the lock.

Comment: Also, at the $120 lock level, what you're mostly paying for is bump and pick resistance, but on these locks that have no keyway to pick, I don't think that'll apply.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, it's a specialty item.  The $120 I mention doesn't include the cylinder, it's a figure 8 type with swappable cylinders.